# Is it possible that Telegram's OTP has been hacked?

Tags: one-time-password, sniffing, telegram

A couple of my friends have been in a kind of pickle recently. There have been attempts to hack their Telegram accounts and hackers somehow learned their one time pass codes but the login attempts were thwarted because my friends had long passwords (second-step verification).

My friends have wildly different setups: these are Windows, Linux and MacOS systems, so it's near impossible that they all have malware stealing OTPs.

I wonder if Telegram has somehow been partially hacked behind the scenes and what experts here think.

In the screenshot below:

- The OTP codes for the Telegram account came over Telegram
- The device listed is the legitimate user's device
- The location is not where the legitimate account is being used (the illegitimate accessor's location)

[image: Telegram log-in attempt thwarted]

Comment: The more likely scenario is that your friend accounts are partially hacked or their Messenger accounts are compromised. The OTP code is going to the attacker devices. Have your friends check their OTP settings to look for unauthorised additions. In addition, SIM swap attacks could also redirect OTP codes sent via Messenger. Check those vectors first before jumping to Telegram as being the vector.

Comment: "What's the flow of activity?" I don't understand this one, others will be added to the question.

Comment: I'm asking for some kind of a timeline. You've posted a screenshot without any context assuming we know all the details. Did your friends trigger a OTP? Did those messages come without any action done by the users?

Comment: *"Did your friends trigger a OTP?"* No *"Did those messages come without any action done by the users?"* Yes, exactly.